# How is the Routhian of classical mechanics defined?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry

The Hamiltonian is a function on the cotangent bundle to a configuration manifold $H:T^*M\rightarrow \mathbb R$. The Lagrangian is a function on the tangent bundle to the configuration manifold $\mathscr L:TM\rightarrow \mathbb R$. What is the [Routhian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics) $R$ defined on?

My guess is $TM\bigoplus T^*M$?

Comment: Isn't that a bit big? I would have thought we want a subbundle of $TM$ corresponding to whatever coordinates are being treated in a Lagrangian way, added to the subbundle of $T^*M$ dual to the complement of this.

Comment: I found what you're looking for, please see my answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265248/beyond-hamiltonian-and-lagrangian-mechanics/265257#265257