# Beyond Hamiltonian and Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory

Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations are the bedrock of particle and field theories, produce the same equations of motion, and are related through a Legendre transform.  Are there more such mathematical objects that are equivalent, or are these two in some way unique?  If so, why are there *two* equivalent systems,  rather than a single (or more)?

Comment: You want mathematically equivalent objects only in the context of Classical mechanics? If not, then you can remember all the different formulations of QM

Comment: I didn't mean that. I thought your question was about other examples of reformulations of the same thing. As an example I mentioned all the different formulations of QM.

Comment: If your question is solely about CM then you might like this post https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-alternative-formulations-of-mechanics-besides-the-usual-Newtonian-and-Lagrangian-ones-Ideally-speaking-should-anymore-be-possible

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39677/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is also the Routhian formalism of mechanics which is described as being a hybrid of Lagrangian and hamiltonian mechanics. The Routhian is defined as $$R = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i\dot{q}_i - L$$ You can learn more about it by clicking this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics) for Wikipedia's description of it.

Reading more in regards to the routhian because I was bored, I realized it is defined as the [partial Legendre transform](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/guan/Legendre-draft-7.pdf) of the Lagrangian and also in the language of differential geometry it is defined similarly to the Lagrangian as $$R^\mu : TM \to \mathbb{R}$$ where $$R^\mu(q, \dot{q}) = L(q, \dot{q}) - \langle A(q, \dot{q}), \mu\rangle$$ where $A$ is the mechanical connection term. You can read more about it in this [pdf](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/1993/04-MaSc1993b/MaSc1993b.pdf).

Comment: I must say I had never heard of this thing before. Interesting!

Comment: @QuantumBrick This answer, like QuantumBrick's, is good thanks.  I was hoping for greater insight into why these few objects  (Hamiltonian/Lagrangian,Routhian, Hamilton-Jacobi) are imbued with magic dust for generating eq. of m.   Maybe its really as simple as a single object that can be cast in different forms via Legendre transform, and thats it.

Comment: It is not at all that simple and it has really nothing to do with Legendre transforms. If you want I can update my answer with an outline of the three main formalisms of mechanics.

Comment: I edited my answer adding more information. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's worth pointing out that the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian formalisms are independent, even though they're usually taught as if the former were a filtering of the latter (here enter Legendre transforms). Both formalisms are as independent as the notions of tangent and cotangent bundles in differential geometry: independent, but intrinsically connected.

Also, there's a third formalism: the Hamilton-Jacobi one. It is as good as the other two, and carries a completelly different interpretation of the equations of motion. All those formalisms are deeply connected an each has its advantages and geometric interpretation.

As a last comment: you can think of many other interpretations of Mechanics. There are as many as you want. An example of a new, yet useful one, is the [centre-chord](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157397000707) interpretation, related to the Weyl-Wigner interpretation os quantum machanics. As long as your transformations are canonical, the sky is the limit regarding the creation of new points of view in Mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

All the various "free energies" of thermodynamics are but a (or sometime a few) Legendre transform(s) away from the plain old energy.

- To get the Helmholtz free energy from the energy you perform a Legendre transformation between entropy and temperature.
- To get the enthalpy from the energy you perform a Legendre transformation between volume and pressure.
- To get the Gibbs free energy from the energy you perform two Legendre transforms, one between entropy and temperature and the other between volume and pressure.
- And so on (there are others, but they are less common in application). In particular you can exchange a description in therms of particle numbers for one in terms of chemical potentials when needed.